# dplyr-0.6.0 programming unquoting

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper to `summarise()` arbitrary variables by arbitrary groups and have made progress now I've got the [correct library version loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183301/dplyr-0-6-0-and-non-standard-evaluation) but am confused (again) about how to unquote arguments with multiple values.

I currently have the following function...

```
table_summary <- function(df     = .,
                          id     = individual_id,
                          select = c(),
                          group  = site,
                          ...){
    ## Quote all arguments (see http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)
    quo_id     <- enquo(id)
    quo_select <- enquo(select)
    quo_group  <- enquo(group)
    ## Subset the data
    df <- df %>%
          dplyr::select(!!quo_id, !!quo_select, !!quo_group) %>%
          unique()
    ## gather() data, just in case there is > 1 variable selected to be summarised
    df <- df %>%
          gather(key = variable, value = value, !!quo_select)
    ## Summarise selected variables by specified groups
    results <- df %>%
           group_by(!!quo_group, variable) %>%
           summarise(n    = n(),
                     mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
    return(results)
}
```

Which gets most of the way there and works if I specify one grouping variable...

```
> table_summary(df = mtcars, id = model, select = c(mpg), group = gear)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   c(gear) [?]
       gear variable     n     mean
      <dbl>    <chr> <int>    <dbl>
1         3      mpg    15 16.10667
2         4      mpg    12 24.53333
3         5      mpg     5 21.38000
```

...but fails at the `group_by(!!quo_group, variable)` when I specify more than one `group = c(gear, hp)`...

```
> mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)
> table_summary(df = mtcars, id = model, select = c(mpg), group = c(gear, hp))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `c(gear, hp)` must be length 32 (the group size) or one, not 64
```

I went back and re-read the [programming dplyr documentation](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) and I read that you can [capture multiple variables](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#capturing-multiple-variables) using `quos()` instead of `enquo()` and then [unquote-splice them with `!!!`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#unquote-splicing), so tried...

```
table_summary <- function(df     = .,
                          id     = individual_id,
                          select = c(),
                          group  = c(),
                          digits = 3,
                          ...){
    ## Quote all arguments (see http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)
    quo_id     <- enquo(id)
    quo_select <- enquo(select)
    quo_group  <- quos(group)  ## Use quos() rather than enquo()
    UQS(quo_group) %>% print() ## Check to see what quo_group holds
    ## Subset the data
    df <- df %>%
          dplyr::select(!!quo_id, !!quo_select, !!!quo_group)) %>%
          unique()
    ## gather() data, just in case there is > 1 variable selected to be summarised
    df <- df %>%
          gather(key = variable, value = value, !!quo_select)
    ## Summarise selected variables by specified groups
    results <- df %>%
               group_by(!!!quo_group, variable) %>%
               summarise(n    = n(),
                         mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
    return(results)
}
```

...which now fails at the first reference to ``` !!!quo_group``within ```dplyr::select()`regardless of how many variables are specified under`group = `...

```
> table_summary(df = mtcars, id = model, select = c(mpg), group = c(gear))
[[1]]
<quosure: frame>
~group

attr(,"class")
[1] "quosures"
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'gear' not found
> traceback()
17: .Call(rlang_eval, f_rhs(quo), overscope)
16: overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr)
15: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
14: lapply(.x, .f, ...)
13: map(.x[matches], .f, ...)
12: map_if(ind_list, !is_helper, eval_tidy, data = names_list)
11: select_vars(names(.data), !(!(!quos(...))))
10: select.data.frame(., !(!quo_id), !(!quo_select), !(!(!quo_group)))
9: dplyr::select(., !(!quo_id), !(!quo_select), !(!(!quo_group)))
8: function_list[[i]](value)
7: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
6: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
5: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
2: df %>% dplyr::select(!(!quo_id), !(!quo_select), !(!(!quo_group))) %>% 
       unique()
1: table_summary(df = mtcars, id = model, select = c(mpg), group = c(gear))
```

What seems strange and I think is the source of the problem is that `!!!quo_group` (i.e. `UQS(quo_group)`) prints out `~gear` rather than a list of quosures as adding a `print()` into the worked examples shows happens...

```
> my_summarise <- function(df, ...) {
    group_by <- quos(...)
    UQS(group_by) %>% print()
    df %>%
    group_by(!!!group_by) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
  }
> df <- tibble(
    g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
    a = sample(5), 
    b = sample(5)
  )
> my_summarise(df, g1, g2)
[[1]]
<quosure: global>
~g1

[[2]]
<quosure: global>
~g2

attr(,"class")
[1] "quosures"
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   g1 [?]
     g1    g2     a
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   1.0
2     1     2   5.0
3     2     1   2.5
4     2     2   4.0
```

I'd like to explicitly supply the variables I wish to group by as a parameter to my argument but does it work if I specify them as `...` but I decided to test if my function works when supplying the grouping variables as `...`

```
table_summary <- function(df     = .,
                          id     = individual_id,
                          select = c(),
                          group  = c(),
                          digits = 3,
                          ...){
    ## Quote all arguments (see http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)
    quo_id     <- enquo(id)
    quo_select <- enquo(select)
    ## quo_group  <- quos(group)
    quo_group  <- quos(...)
    UQS(quo_group) %>% print()
    ## Subset the data
    df <- df %>%
          dplyr::select(!!quo_id, !!quo_select, !!!quo_group) %>%
          unique()
    ## gather() data, just in case there is > 1 variable selected to be summarised
    df <- df %>%
          gather(key = variable, value = value, !!quo_select)
    ## Summarise selected variables by specified groups
    results <- df %>%
               group_by(!!!quo_group, variable) %>%
               summarise(n    = n(),
                         mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
    return(results)
}
```

...but it doesn't, `quos()` again unquote-splices to `NULL` so the variables are neither selected nor grouped by...

```
> table_summary(df = mtcars, id = model, select = c(mpg), gear, hp)
NULL
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  variable     n     mean
     <chr> <int>    <dbl>
1      mpg    32 20.09062
> table_summary(df = mtcars, id = model, select = c(mpg), gear)
NULL
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  variable     n     mean
     <chr> <int>    <dbl>
1      mpg    32 20.09062
```

I've gone through this cycle several times now checking each method of using `enquo()` and `quos()` but can not see where I am going wrong and despite having read the programming dplyr documentation several times.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC your post, you want to supply `c(col1, col2)` to `group_by()`. This is not supported by that verb:

```
group_by(mtcars, c(cyl, am))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
#>   Column `c(cyl, am)` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one, not 64
```

That's because `group_by()` has *mutate* semantics, not *select* semantics. That means that the expressions you supply to `group_by()` are transformative expressions. This is a surprising but quite handy feature. For example you can group by `disp` cut into three intervals like this:

```
group_by(mtcars, cut3 = cut(disp, 3))
```

This also means that if you supply `c(cyl, am)`, it will concatenate the two columns together and return a vector of length 64, while it was expecting a length of 32 (the number of rows).

So your problem is that you want a wrapper to `group_by()` that has selection semantics. This is easy to do by using `dplyr::select_vars()`, which will soon be extracted to the new tidyselect package:

```
library("dplyr")

group_wrapper <- function(df, groups = rlang::chr()) {
  groups <- select_vars(tbl_vars(df), !! enquo(groups))
  group_by(df, !!! rlang::syms(groups))
}
```

Alternatively you can wrap the new `group_by_at()` verb which does have select semantics:

```
group_wrapper <- function(df, groups = rlang::chr()) {
  group_by_at(df, vars(!! enquo(groups)))
}
```

Let's try it out:

```
group_wrapper(mtcars, c(disp, am))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#> # Groups:   disp, am [27]
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21.0     6   160   110  3.90  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

This interface has the advantage of supporting all `select()` operations to select the columns to group by.

Note that I'm using `rlang::chr()` as default argument because `c()` returns `NULL` which isn't supported by selecting functions (we may want to change that in the future). `chr()` called without arguments returns a character vector of length 0.